# Python Tkinter GUI - Search Files In Directory For Instances Of A String

Tags: python, tkinter, gui

This script opens a basic form which allows one to search all files in a directory for instances of a string, before outputting results to a textbox and CSV (found in the script location). Each line outputted is of the format:

> Word **{string}** in **{file}** on line **{line number}**: **{full line}**

**Steps:**

1. Specify Directory
2. Input string you would like to search for
3. Toggle ignore case on or off
4. Click Go.

**Notes:**

This is not completely finished yet. Script will only search basic TXT files. I'm also a beginner with Tkinter/GUIs, so haven't moved buttons around, etc. I've just added the buttons & labels one after the other. This will eventually be rectified. There's also an issue where if I'm searching a large directory of files, the form will look like it's frozen until it's finished searching. Finally, I may have went overboard on some of the error handling. I'm newish to this as well.

I'm trying to be a better programmer, particularly with structuring and readability, so any constructive criticism would be much appreciated.

[image]

```
from tkinter import filedialog

from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText

import pandas as pd

import tkinter as tk

import os

import re

import sys

################ FUNCTIONS ################

def save_to_file(wordlist):
    """Save list to CSV format and save CSV to script directory"""
    script_directory = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]) # Path where script is being run from
    df = pd.DataFrame(data={"Results": wordlist})
    df.to_csv(script_directory+"/mycsv.csv", sep=",", index=False, line_terminator='\n')
    
def print_to_textbox(wordlist):
    """Print all lines in wordlist to textbox"""
    for lines in wordlist:
        text_box.insert("end", "\n"+lines)
    if len(wordlist) == 0:
        text_box.insert("1.0", "\nNothing To Display")

def browse_button():
    """Button will open a window for directory selection"""
    global folder_path
    selected_directory = filedialog.askdirectory()
    folder_path.set(selected_directory)
    
def search_files():
    """Search all files in specified directory"""
    folderPath = folder_path.get()
    searchString = string_entry.get()
    text_box.delete("1.0", tk.END)
    
    # Set word case option on/off.
    if var1.get() == 1:
        IGNOREWORDCASE = True
    else:
        IGNOREWORDCASE = False
        
    # List to store all lines where string is found.
    wordlist = []  
    
    # Loop through all files and search for string, line by line.
    for (path, directories, files) in os.walk(folderPath, topdown=True):
        for file in files:
            filepath = os.path.join(path, file)
            
            try: 
                
                with open(filepath, 'r') as currentfile:          
                        for lineNum, line in enumerate(currentfile, 1):  
                            line = line.strip()
                            match = re.search(searchString, line, re.IGNORECASE) if IGNOREWORDCASE else re.search(searchString, line)
                            if match:
                                word = f"Word '{searchString}' in '{file}' on line {lineNum}: {line}"
                                wordlist.append(word)
                                
            except IOError as ex:
                words = f"Error; {file}; {ex}"
                wordlist.insert(0, words)
                
            except EnvironmentError as ex:
                words = f"Error; {file}; {ex}"
                wordlist.insert(0, words)
                
            except OSError as ex:
                words = f"Error; {file}; {ex}"
                wordlist.insert(0, words)
                
            except UnicodeDecodeError as ex:
                words = f"Error; {file}; {ex}"
                wordlist.insert(0, words)
                
            except:
                words = f"Error; {file}"
                wordlist.insert(0, words)

    # Print all lines to text box.
    print_to_textbox(wordlist)
    
    # Save to file.
    save_to_file(wordlist)
                
################ TKINTER SCRIPT ################

# Setup Window.
window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("900x500")
window.title("String Search")

# Button to select directory.
select_directory = tk.Button(window, text = "Select Directory", command=browse_button)
select_directory.pack()

# Label to store chosen directory.
folder_path = tk.StringVar()
directory_label = tk.Label(window, textvariable = folder_path, bg="#D3D3D3", width=70)
directory_label.pack()

# Entry to type search string.
string_entry = tk.Entry(window, bg="#D3D3D3")
string_entry.pack()

# Check button to turn ignore case on/off.
var1 = tk.IntVar()
stringCase_select = tk.Checkbutton(window, text='Ignore Case',variable=var1, onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
stringCase_select.pack()

# Button to run main script.
go_button = tk.Button(window, text="Go", command=search_files)
go_button.pack()

# Button to quit the app.
quit_button = tk.Button(window, text = "Quit", command=window.quit)
quit_button.pack()

# Text box to display output of main text.
text_box = ScrolledText(width=110, borderwidth=2, relief="sunken", padx=20)
text_box.pack()

# Button to clear the text box display.
clear_button = tk.Button(window, text = "Clear", command = lambda: text_box.delete("1.0", tk.END))
clear_button.pack()

# Run an event loop.
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## PEP-8

To maintain consistency while writing code, Python code follows the [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#:%7E:text=Use%20the%20function%20naming%20rules,invoke%20Python%27s%20name%20mangling%20rules.) naming convention. For example

[Source](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#:%7E:text=Use%20the%20function%20naming%20rules,invoke%20Python%27s%20name%20mangling%20rules.)

> Function names should be lowercase, with words separated by
> underscores as necessary to improve readability.
>
> Variable names follow the same convention as function names.

The library that you are currently using, which is `tkinter` also follows the same naming convention. You can see that classes like `Button`,`Canvas`, and `StringVar()`. All follow the `CamelCase` since they are classes.

## Positioning widgets in your application

Although `.pack()` works, you will soon see its limits when you start trying to position the widgets in specific places, like an **exit button** typically stays in the corner, A **title** usually is placed at the top. In these scenarios `.pack()` is just very limited.

A common way is to use `.place()` to position widgets in your application. It has many arguments like `bordermode` and `anchor` to customize your task, the two main are `x` and `y` which are basically just the horizontal and vertical points at which your widget will be placed.

Here is a simple Tkinter window of `geometry("500x500")` I have created to show the usage of `place()`. It also has a `Label` as a simple widget.
[image: window]

Example: `widget.place(x = 300,y = 50)`

[image: window2]

You get to decide where you want to place your widgets accurately.

## Structuring a `Tk` application

@Reinderien suggested your `TKINTER_SCRIPT` into a function. This makes sense because you already have good functions like `search_files()`, why would you have your Tkinter application in the main scope?

While some might disagree, my suggestion is that you opt for an **Object-oriented approach**, which will help keep your code clean. In your situation, it makes sense to have a single `MainApplication()` class. Here is a simple example of what that would look like

```py
class MainApplication:
    def __init__(self,window,size = "500x500"):
        self.window = window
        window.geometry(size)
        self.entry_box = # Entry box widget
        self.title = # Title label 
        # More widgets that are relevant to MainApplication

    def close_application():
        # print any messages on window like "Thank you for using..."
        self.window.close()

root = tk.Tk()
window = MainApplication(root)

root.mainloop()
```

[Structuring a Tkinter application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466561/best-way-to-structure-a-tkinter-application)

### Small suggestions

- Use `root.iconbitmap( #icon image )` to set a `16x16` icon for your tkinter application, this will appear instead of the little feather that comes
- `Tkinter` has a huge variety of widgets, it is possible that you might find a new one from this [list of main widgets](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-classes.htm) that might be perfect for your application.
- [message boxes in tkinter](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/tkinter.messagebox.html) will be suitable for when a user might do something wrong, or maybe you want to get a confirmation.

Example of a message box 
[image: yn]

Comment: This is brilliant, thanks! I'll take a look through all this tonight and tomorrow and let you know how I get on. Still trying to wrap my head around OOP. For the sample you've provided, should I be keeping my functions (e.g. `search_files()`) as functions and adding them as methods inside the MainApplication Class?

Comment: @AaronWright No, `search_files` has nothing to do with your GUI, hence you should either keep a class that would handle the files, or a few functions would work too

Comment: Okay. I'll aim to create another class to deal with this. I presume all the widgets for the form will need to be declared within the `MainApplication` Class?

Comment: @AaronWright Yes, I feel like you should have a look at some good programs made in tkinter. You can find several on github. This will give you some nice ideas

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look! I have tried to find a good script on GitHub but never had much luck. Do you have any suggestions? I'm also trying to covert my other script that I submitted here (regarding a book library) to an tkinter application and have been struggling to implement it. It may be too advanced for me.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using PEP-484 type hints for your function signatures.

Use a linter like `pyflakes`, `flake8` or `black` that will give you a number of suggestions about your code format.

Move your `TKINTER SCRIPT` into one or more functions, instead of in global scope.

Use `pathlib`, so that this:

```
script_directory+"/mycsv.csv
```

can be

```
Path(script_directory) / 'mycsv.csv'
```

If `var1.get()` returns 0/1, then you can simply write

```
IGNORE_WORD_CASE = bool(var1.get())
```

though you should give `var1` a more meaningful name.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know much about type hints, but I'll look them up. And great additional suggestions. Is it standard practice to have the main tkinter script into a function?

Comment: @AaronWright you can have an Object-oriented approach too, check this [What is the best way to structure a tkinter application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466561/best-way-to-structure-a-tkinter-application)

Comment: @AryanParekh Thanks. Yes I have this (and another) script I would like to convert to OOP style. However I'm struggling with it a bit. Do you know where I could find a good, simple, OOP program with Tkinter so I could see the general structure? The examples given in that link show how you might start it, but it would be good to see a full script.

Comment: OOP is an option, but not the only one. It's also possible to simply throw everything into a `main` function, which would still be better than what you have (particularly for unit testing).